# How to move to the page from a frameset?

Tags: html, html-frames

in my website, I have a page which have 3 frames, lets say left_frame, top_frame and bottom_frame.
In top_frame, i have a link `<a href="some_page.php">Click</a>`. Currently, this some_page.php is loaded inside the top_frame but i want to completely load a new page. Is there any way out?

Comment: frames aren't recommended, you might want to use `div`s. Very often that does the trick without frames. Also: Google doesn't index pages inside frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<a href="some_page.php" target="_top">Click</a>
```

Comment: @baig772: Accepting an answer always helps say *thank you*. :)